# Does .gitignore not ignore directories that contain .git subdirectories?

Tags: git

I am having trouble getting my Git .gitignore file to ignore the directories that contain my Vim plugin bundle directories.  I'm running Git version 2.22.0 on macOS Mojave.  I run Vim 8.0 and use Vundle to manage my Vim plugins.  My Vim plugin directory structure looks like this:

```
/Users/smith/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
/Users/smith/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/ansible-vim
/Users/smith/dotfiles/ctrlp.vim
...
```

The root of my Git directory is /Users/smith/dotfiles.

Each of these bundle directories contains its own Git repo such that when I run "git status" I'll see something like this for each directory:

```
modified:   .gitignore
modified:   .vim/bundle/Vundle.vim (new commits)
...
```

I didn't know how to install these bundles using Vundle in such a way as to ignore each bundle's .git directory.  Perhaps I should have used submodules, but I didn't.

I don't think I really need to track these bundle directories and would prefer to just have Git ignore them.  But no matter what I put in my .gitignore file, whenever I run "git status" I still see these bundle directories with new commits.

Here is my .gitignore:

```
other/ipythop/profile_default/history.sqlite
.DS_Store
.vim/.netrwhist
.vim/bundle/
*.*.swp
```

I've tried many things:

```
.vim/bundle/
.vim/bundle
.vim/bundle/*
```

I've even tried to include each directory like this but that doesn't prevent them from appearing either:

```
.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `git log -- .vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`?

Comment: Actually as I look at it, they're all the same.  commit <hash> \n Author: <my name> <email> \n Date <a date last year> \n <a comment I wrote in January of 2018>

Comment: that output indicates that the files are already being tracked in version control. Adding tracked files to `.gitignore` does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the output you've provided, you are in fact using submodules. The `(new commits)` text is only displayed for submodules. It *is* possible that you don't have a `.gitmodules` file, since they are not strictly needed for submodules, although they are usually recommended.

If you don't want to track these as submodules, you can run `git rm` to remove it, although be aware that will likely remove the Git repository there, so back up anything you want that's there. You can then add those paths to your `.gitignore` file, and Git will properly ignore them. Git is not ignoring them now because adding them to `.gitignore` does nothing if they're already tracked.

If you want to add them as submodules, then you can create an empty `.gitmodules` file and run `git submodule add` (possibly with the `-f` parameter if necessary) to set up remotes for them.

Comment: `git rm --cached <path>` should remove the gitlink entry without removing the submodule repo/work-tree.